# PrimeFaces tag for JSF h:inputHidden

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Does someone have any recommendations for PrimeFaces tags? To be specific, I am trying to find equivalent PrimeFaces tag for input type hidden.

Can someone tell, if we have PrimeFaces tag for JSF `<h:inputHidden>` input type hidden?

Comment: Why not use h:inputHidden?? I think there is not a component in primefaces for a hidden field

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a JSF pause and start learning some basic HTML. Once you know basic HTML, you'll quickly realize that your question absolutely doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use p:inputText and set type="hidden"

```
<p:inputText value="hello world" id="hiddenfield" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this compared to just using `h:inputText`?

Comment: Also does anyone know if there is way to render the hidden type within the html?

Comment: @nek : if you found answer as right approach please mark it as answer so other can refer it.

Answer (score 3):

PrimeFaces use

```
<h:inputHidden id="..." value="..." />
```

For example:

```
<h:inputHidden id="txt2" value="#{sliderView.number2}" />
```

Reference: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml
(See line 13th in file `slider.xhml` source code)